Given Random Variables X, Y joint distribution function, show that X and Y are jointly continuously distributed -- where is my error?
I'm working on the following problem:

Given that Random Variables $X,Y$ have joint distribution function
$$
\operatorname{F}_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right) = \begin{cases}
 0, & x < 0
\\
{\displaystyle\left(1 - {\rm e}^{-x}\right)
\left[\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(y\right)\right]}, &
0 \leq x
\end{cases}
$$
show that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly continuously distributed.

My thought was to check that the following conditions are met:
$$
\begin{array}{r,l}
\left(1\right) & \displaystyle\operatorname{f}\left(x,y\right) \geq 0
\\[2mm]
\left(2\right) &
\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{f}\left(x,y\right){\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y = 1
\end{array}
$$
To find the PDF $\operatorname{f}\left(x,y\right)$ we can differentiate the distribution function with respect to $x$ and $y$ to get $$
\operatorname{f}\left(x,y\right) =
\frac{{\rm e}^{-x}}{\pi\left(y^{2} + 1\right)}
$$
Clearly condition $\left(1\right)$ is met since this function is non-negative. But when I integrate this function over $0$ to infinity for $x$ and $y$, I get $1/2$ instead of $1$. What am I doing wrong ?.

You say "integrate this function over 0 to infinity for  and ", but the range of y is minus infinity to infinity.  And since your f is even in y, that seems to explain why you obtained an integral of 1/2.
